# Determine if cell is not empty, to select a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to use For/If/Else to return various ranges depending on whether a certain cell is not empty, then paste that range into an email.

The code below returns range B15:G20, no matter if the cell in question (b20) is empty or not. Ideally I'd like to test up to four cells to see if they're not empty and return a range that only contains cells with data in them.

```
Sub EXPVendorCopyRangeToOutlook_single()
    'Declare Outlook Vairables
    Dim oLookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oLookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    
    'Declare Word Vaiables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'Get the Active instance of Outlook
    Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
    'If error create a new instance of outlook
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        'Clear Error
        Err.Clear
        
        'Create new instance of Outlook
        Set oLookApp = New Outlook.Application
        
    End If
    'Create a new email 'Possible Problem here
    Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'Create a reference to the ex range you want to export
    
    For Each Cell In Worksheets("sheet1")
        If Not IsEmpty(b20.Value) Then
            Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g20")
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(b19.Value) Then
            Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g18")
        End If
    Next
        
    With oLookItm
    
        'Define basic info
        .From = "ABC@XYZ.COM"
        
        .To = "123@345.COM"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = Range("m3")
        
        .Body = "Please review the attached invoices and confirm that the goods or services have been received and payment should be made."
        
        'Display email
        .Display
        'Get the active inspector
        Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
        
        'Get word editor
        Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor
        
        'Specify rang in document
        Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
            oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
        'Add new paragraphand then insert break
        Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraph.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
        
        'Copy the Range
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Paste it
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the part of the code giving me problems.

```
For Each Cell In Worksheets("sheet1")
    If Not IsEmpty(b20.Value) Then
        Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g20")
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(b19.Value) Then
        Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g18")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: you're missing the Range reference. Try  IsEmpty(Range(B20).Value) and see if that works any better.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` should be cancelled with `On Error Goto 0` once you've set up the outlook application object.  Otherwise your code happily skips over any errors without flagging them up.

Comment: I updated code to For Each Cell In Worksheets("sheet1")
        If Not IsEmpty(Range(b20).Value) Then
            Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g20")
        ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Range(b19).Value) Then
            Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("b15:g18")
        End If   It pastes the range, which it was doing before, it just won't, even after above suggestion,  change based on empty cells.

Comment: Is `b20.Value` valid syntax? Try `Range("B20").Value`, and same for `B19`?  Also, I'm almost positive you don't want to check every cell in the worksheet? And why are you looping, you're checking the same cell's value over and over...

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax, VBA is not my strong suit. but it works as is to set the range i want to  past.  it will past something.  It's just not dynamic. I don't want to check every cell, i had a range to check in there and i took it out to test something and forgot to put it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There we go, I had some of the syntax wrong
`For Each Cell In Worksheets("sheet10").Range("b20:g25")
If Not IsEmpty(Sheet10.Range("b25").Value) Then
Set ExcRng = Sheet10.Range("b20:g25")
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheet10.Range("b24").Value) Then
Set ExcRng = Sheet10.Range("b20:g24")
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheet10.Range("b23").Value) Then
Set ExcRng = Sheet10.Range("b20:g23")
ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Sheet10.Range("b22").Value) Then
Set ExcRng = Sheet10.Range("b20:g22")
End If
Next